# Java Concurrency JDK 1.6: Busy wait does better than signalling? Effective Java #51

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java", Item 51 is not about depending on the thread scheduler as well as not keeping threads unnecessarily in the runnable state. Quoted text:

> The main technique for keeping the number of runnable threads down is to have each thread 
>   do a small amount of work and then wait for some condition using Object.wait or for some 
>   time to elapse using Thread.sleep. Threads should not busy-wait, repeatedly checking a data 
>   structure  waiting  for  something  to  happen.  Besides  making  the  program  vulnerable  to  the 
>   vagaries  of  the  scheduler,  busy-waiting  can  greatly  increase  the  load  on  the  processor, 
>   reducing the amount of useful work that other processes can accomplish on the same machine.

And then goes on to show a microbenchmark of a busy wait vs using signals properly. In the book, the busy wait does 17 round trips/s whereas the wait/notify version does 23,000 round trips per second.

However, when I tried the same benchmark on JDK 1.6, I see just the opposite - the busy wait does 760K roundtrips/second whereas the wait/notify version does 53.3K roundtrips/s - that is, wait/notify should have been ~1400 times faster, but turns out to be ~13 times slower?

I understand the busy waits aren't good and signalling is still better - cpu utilization is ~50% on the busy wait version whereas it stays at ~30% on the wait/notify version - but is there something that explains the numbers?

If it helps, I'm running JDK1.6 (32 bit) on Win 7 x64 (core i5).

**UPDATE**: Source below. To run the busy work bench, change the base class of PingPongQueue to BusyWorkQueue
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

```
abstract class SignalWorkQueue { 
    private final List queue = new LinkedList(); 
    private boolean stopped = false; 

    protected SignalWorkQueue() { new WorkerThread().start(); } 

    public final void enqueue(Object workItem) { 
        synchronized (queue) { 
            queue.add(workItem); 
            queue.notify(); 
        } 
    } 

    public final void stop()  { 
        synchronized (queue) { 
            stopped = true; 
            queue.notify(); 
        } 
    } 
    protected abstract void processItem(Object workItem) 
        throws InterruptedException; 
    private class WorkerThread extends Thread { 
        public void run() { 
            while (true) {  // Main loop 
                Object workItem = null; 
                synchronized (queue) { 
                    try { 
                        while (queue.isEmpty() && !stopped) 
                            queue.wait(); 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                        return; 
                    } 
                    if (stopped) 
                        return; 
                    workItem = queue.remove(0); 
                } 
                try { 
                    processItem(workItem); // No lock held 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    return; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}

// HORRIBLE PROGRAM - uses busy-wait instead of Object.wait! 
abstract class BusyWorkQueue {
    private final List queue = new LinkedList();
    private boolean stopped = false;

    protected BusyWorkQueue() {
        new WorkerThread().start();
    }

    public final void enqueue(Object workItem) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.add(workItem);
        }
    }

    public final void stop() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            stopped = true;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void processItem(Object workItem)
            throws InterruptedException;

    private class WorkerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            final Object QUEUE_IS_EMPTY = new Object();
            while (true) { // Main loop
                Object workItem = QUEUE_IS_EMPTY;
                synchronized (queue) {
                    if (stopped)
                        return;
                    if (!queue.isEmpty())
                        workItem = queue.remove(0);
                }

                if (workItem != QUEUE_IS_EMPTY) {
                    try {
                        processItem(workItem);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class PingPongQueue extends SignalWorkQueue {
    volatile int count = 0;

    protected void processItem(final Object sender) {
        count++;
        SignalWorkQueue recipient = (SignalWorkQueue) sender;
        recipient.enqueue(this);
    }
}

public class WaitQueuePerf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PingPongQueue q1 = new PingPongQueue();
        PingPongQueue q2 = new PingPongQueue();
        q1.enqueue(q2); // Kick-start the system

        // Give the system 10 seconds to warm up
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        // Measure the number of round trips in 10 seconds
        int count = q1.count;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println(q1.count - count);

        q1.stop();
        q2.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your test, the queue gets new items continuously, therefore the busy-wait does very little actual waiting.

If the queue get one new item every 1ms, you can see the busy-wait will spend most time burning CPU for nothing. It will slow down other part of the application.

So it depends. If you busy wait on an user input, that is definitely wrong; while the busy-wait in lockless datastructures like AtomicInteger is definitely good.

Comment: I think that's it. Just tried it out. With a 1ms sleep introduced before dropping the item in the other queue, both runs do pretty much the same - about 400 roundtrips/s. As expected, the busy wait uses up 3 times more of the CPU. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, busy wait will respond more quickly and execute more loops, but I think the point was that it puts an disproportionally heavier load on the entire system.

Try running 1000 busy wait threads vs 1000 wait/notify threads and check your total throughput.

I think the difference you observed is probably sun re-optimizing the compiler for what people do rather than what people should do.  Sun does that all the time.  The original benchmark in the book may have even been due to some scheduler bug that Sun fixed--with that ratio it certainly sounds wrong.

Comment: Well, the book seems to suggest that you 'always' pay a penalty using busy waits - even when you just have a couple of threads. Also, the numbers quoted indicate just that. I see the increased utilization and definitely understand what'll happen if you have enough other threads. So - still puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on the amount of threads and the degree of conflicts: Busy waits are bad, if happens often and/or consume many CPU cycles.

But atomic Integers (AtomicInteger, AtomicIntegerArray ...) are better than synchronzing an Integer or int[], even the thread also perfom busy waits.

Use the java.util.concurrent package and in your case ConcurrentLinkedQueueas often as possible

Answer (score 0):

Busy waiting is not always a bad thing. "Proper" (at the low-level) way of doing things - using Java synchronization primitives - carries an overhead, oftentimes significant, of bookkeeping, necessary to implement general-purpose mechanisms, performing fairly well in most scenarios. Busy waiting, on the other hand, is very lightweight, and in some situations can be quite an improvement over the one-size-fits-all synchronization. While synchronization based solely on busy-waiting is definitely a no-no in any general setting, it's ocassionaly quite useful. It's true not only for Java - spinlocks (fancy name for busy-waiting based locks) are widely used in database servers, for instance.

In fact, if you take a walk through java.util.concurrent package sources, you'll find many places containing "tricky", seemingly fragile code. I find `SynchronousQueue` a nice example (you can take a look at the source in JDK distribution or [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.java), both OpenJDK and Oracle seem to use the same implementation). Busy waiting is used as an optimization - after certain amount of "spins", the thread goes into proper "sleep". Apart from that, it has some other niceties as well - volatile piggybacking, spin treshold dependant on number of CPUs etc. It's really... illuminating, in that it shows what it takes to implement efficient low-level concurrency. Even better, the **code** itself is really clean, well-documented and high-quality in general.